# pytorch subset on dataloader decrease number of data

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-dataloader

i'm using random_split()

```
dataset_train, dataset_valid = random_split(dataset, [int(len(dataset) * 0.8), int(len(dataset) * 0.2+1)])
```

len(dataset_train) is 1026 and len(dataset_valid) is 257 but put this two vriable into dataloader decrease number of data

```
loader_train = DataLoader(dataset_train, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True, num_workers=0)
loader_val = DataLoader(dataset_valid, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True, num_workers=0)
print (len(loader_train))
print (len(loader_val))
```

output is :

```
257, 65
```

I don't know why decrease the size of dataset.
please any help. thanks.

Comment: Try batch_size=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`data.Subset`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.Subset) which works as a wrapper for [`data.Dataset`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.Dataset) instances. You need to provide a generator or list of indices that you want to retain in the constructed dataset

1. Here is a minimal setup example:

   ```
   >>> dataset_train = data.TensorDataset(torch.arange(100))
   ```
2. Construct the subset by wrapping `dataset_train`:

   ```
   >>> subset = data.Subset(ds, range(10)) # will select the first 10 of dataset_train
   ```
3. Finally construct your dataloader:

   ```
   >>> loader_train = data.DataLoader(subset, batch_size=2)
   ```

---

As an illustration here is `loader_train`:

```
>>> for x in dl:
...    print(x)
[tensor([0, 1])]
[tensor([2, 3])]
[tensor([4, 5])]
[tensor([6, 7])]
[tensor([8, 9])]
```